# Android write to file not working

Tags: android, writetofile

I am a beginner when it comes to Android. I encountered a problem, regarding writing to a file. I want to save to a file the input I get in a form. However, the piece of code that I wrote is not writing in my file. Could anyone please help me?
The code looks like that:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
          s.append("Event name: " + editText1.getText() + "|");
          s.append("Date: " + editText2.getText() +  "|");
          s.append("Details: " + editText3.getText() + "|");

          File file = new File("D:\\config.txt");
          try {
              BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true), 1024);
                out.write(s.toString());
                out.newLine();
                out.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
});
```

So, I have a form containing 3 fields: the name of an event, the date and the description. These I want to save to my file. I should mention that I use an emulator for testing.

Comment: obviosuly there is no "D:\" in android

Comment: how should i mention the path?

Comment: Read this [documentation regarding saving the files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following path for file. It will write file to your root folder of storage.

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file= new File(extStorageDirectory, "config.txt");

writeToFile("File content".getBytes(), file);
```

**writeToFile**

```
public static void writeToFile(byte[] data, File file) throws IOException {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(data);
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            try {
                bos.flush ();
                bos.close ();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Now I should be able to see the saved file externally, right? But I can't find it.

Comment: Which android version are you using? Make sure you provide permission if you are using android 6 or later version

Comment: Thank you, @user12345, I am using an emulated Nexus with Android 7.0

Comment: Use it on real device

Comment: Accept the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/rznazn/GPS-Data-Logger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/gpsdatalogger/StorageManager.java

Here is a... nearly complete class for writing to the documents folder on the emulated external storage of the device.

Don't forget to add the write permissions to manifest.